# Как включить монитор в Linux?

Tags: mandriva, gnome, linux

На ОС Mandriva Linux 2010.2 (Gnome) по тупости отключил монитор в настройках видеорежима в контрольном центре Мандрива. Теперь во время загрузки монитор в какой-то момент просто переходит в энергосберегающий режим. Пытался загрузиться в безопасном режиме, ввожу в консоли startx, линукс грузится, картинка есть, но мышь и клавиатура не работают (курсор есть, но не перемещается). Как мне включить монитор или сбросить настройки графики по умолчанию?

Answer (score 1):

1)Берешь лайв-сд систему.Грузишься,монитруешь(подробнее о загрузке и монтировании-гугл,там несложно в приницпе).Идешь в свежесмонтированую систему,у тебя полный рут на все должен быть теоретически.Если нет-логинешься под рутом через терминал/консоль.Запускаешь МС(Миднайт Командер).Если нет его то прикидываешь/узнаешь путь до конфиг файла иксоргов(как уже было сказано выше /etc/X11/xorg.conf).То есть у тебя этот путь может быть вида /mnt/disk/etc/X11/xorg.conf.Перед этим скопируй его для пущей надежности.Иначе говоря смотри как все это обтяпать в командах.

Загрузка

Монтирование(mount -опции монтируем то-то и туда-то

бэкап файла(через команду cp -a)

Удаляем файл.(rm)

---

Loading

mkdir /mnt/disk(содаем папку для монитрования)

ls /dev/sd*(тут мы выискиваем устройство нам нужное.Скажем оно будет /dev/sda3

mount rw /dev/sda3 /mnt/disk(тут монтируем нашу выбраную фаловую систему в указаную папку)

ls /mnt/disk(делаем листинг директорий.Смотрим что и как.Если угадали файловую систему и примонтировали корень-все хорошо.Иначе размонтируем(читать ман) и снова монтируем.Так до полного просветления в мозгах)) )

cp -a /mnt/disk/etc/X11/xorg.conf /mnt/disk/etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak(если команда сработала-примонтировали правильно)) )

rm /mnt/disk/etc/X11/xorg.conf(удаляем иксорг.конф)

umount /dev/sda3 /mnt/disk (размонтируем)

Перезагружаемся.

Если не помогло.Может быть и такое.Например есть системы в котороых ксоргконф-неважен.Вернее не важны вот эти настройи.Тогда второй путь.

Грузимся в режиме востановления(кстати я не учел этого.Возможно мандрива умеет сразу грузится в режиме востановления и до "голого шела").Если так-нам повезло.Обойдемся малой кровью.Читаем мануал по...вроде по полному удалению пакета в рпм системе(если есть такое),удаляем пакет Xorg.Еще раз подтираем все хвосты.Ставим пакет заново(необходимо рабочее соединение с инетом).Также советую переустановить некоторые пакеты связаные с иксоргом.Например xserver-xorg-input-evdev(у меня без него тоже мышь и клава не отвечали.Был утерян при неудачном обновлении) и пакет dbus тоже переустановить на всякий случай.Говорю только те решения которые показывали удачный результат на моей системе.Перезагружаемся.

Если и тут ничего не помогло...

1.Переустановить систему.

2.Позвать линуксойда что поближе.

3.Дать знатоку SSH доступ к системе.Путь творит что считает нужным.

Фух....устал писать многабукаф)))Возможны многие ашипко)))

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй удалить файл /etc/X11/xorg.conf